# Filling in a missing statement that continues to read an integer from the user if the user enters 0

Tags: python

```py
num = int(input("Enter a numerator: "))

divisor = 0

while divisor == 0:

    # MISSING STATEMENT

result = num / divisor

print("The result =", result)
```

I am a bit confused as I realize there is a missing statement in the code but it says the divisor=0 which doesn't make sense since you'd get an error statement as you cannot divide by 0. The question asks to fill in the missing statement but even if I do, I don't know what to do about the divisor=0 as the questions doesn't ask to change that.

Comment: I think the assignment is about handling exceptions, such as dividing by zero.

Comment: you have to ask user for `divisor` - it can't be zero. And you need `divisor = 0` because code needs variable `divisor` to check `while divisor == 0:` - but you can't create variable `divisor` without assigning value. In this situation `divisor = 0` is only default value at start - it is popular method - but you have to ask user for new value - until it will be different then zero.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask user for correct `divisor`

```
num = int(input("Enter a numerator: "))

divisor = 0

while divisor == 0:
    divisor = int(input("Enter a divisor: "))

result = num / divisor

print("The result =", result)
```

In this situation `divisor = 0` is default value set at start so `while` can start work.

It is popular method to run loop - first set wrong value (`zero`, `None`, `False`, `empty string`, etc) and next run loop until you get correct value.

Other method is to use `while True` for this - and then you don't need default value at start

```
num = int(input("Enter a numerator: "))

while True:
    divisor = int(input("Enter a divisor: "))
    if divisor != 0:
        break

result = num / divisor

print("The result =", result)
```